# How can I change font line size in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, fonts, documents, truetype-fonts

I installed a google font (.otf) to use it in MS Word. The problem is that with the same font size (11px), the selection highlight is much bigger, and also the line space is different.

[font size disparity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40KEV.png)

If I try to fix the paragraph line space to something like 16px, then when I export to PDF the result is this:

[pdf highlight size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp05C.png)

The highlight size is the same. What can I do to make the font smaller in size ?